# Python - class __hash__ method and set

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, set, python-datamodel

I'm using `set()` and `__hash__` method of `python` class to prevent adding same hash object in set. According to [python data-model document](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), `set()` consider same hash object as same object and just add them once.

But it behaves different as below:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __hash__(self):
        return 0

result = set()
result.add(MyClass())
result.add(MyClass())

print(len(result)) # len = 2
```

While in case of string value, it works correctly.

```
result.add('aida')
result.add('aida')

print(len(result)) # len = 1
```

My question is: why the same hash objects are not same in set?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your reading is incorrect. The `__eq__` method is used for equality checks. The documents just state that the `__hash__` value must also be the same for 2 objects `a` and `b` for which `a == b` (i.e.  `a.__eq__(b)`) is true.

This is a common logic mistake: `a == b` being true *[implies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional)* that `hash(a) == hash(b)` is also true. However, an implication does not necessarily mean *[equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence)*, that in addition to the prior, `hash(a) == hash(b)` would mean that `a == b`.

To make all instances of `MyClass` compare equal to each other, you need to provide an `__eq__` method for them; otherwise Python will compare their *identities instead*. This might do:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __hash__(self):
        return 0
    def __eq__(self, other):
        # another object is equal to self, iff 
        # it is an instance of MyClass
        return isinstance(other, MyClass)
```

Now:

```
>>> result = set()
>>> result.add(MyClass())
>>> result.add(MyClass())
1
```

---

In reality you'd base the `__hash__` on those properties of your object that are used for `__eq__` comparison, for example:

```
class Person
    def __init__(self, name, ssn):
        self.name = name
        self.ssn = ssn

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Person) and self.ssn == other.ssn

    def __hash__(self):
        # use the hashcode of self.ssn since that is used
        # for equality checks as well
        return hash(self.ssn)

p = Person('Foo Bar', 123456789)
q = Person('Fake Name', 123456789)
print(len({p, q})  # 1
```

Comment: Is there any way to pick which object remains in the set? As in prefer `'Foo Bar'` over `'Fake Name'`?

Comment: @alliefitter no. not with hash and eq

Answer (score 16):

Sets need **two** methods to make an object hashable: `__hash__` and `__eq__`. Two instances **must** return the same hash value when they are considered equal. An instance is considered already present in a set if both the hash is present in the set *and* the instance is considered equal to one of the instances with that same hash in the set.

Your class doesn't implement `__eq__`, so the default `object.__eq__` is used instead, which only returns true if `obj1 is obj2` is also true. In other words, two instances are only considered equal if they are *the exact same instance*.

Just because their hashes match, doesn't make them unique as far as a set is concerned; even objects with different hashes can end up in the same hash table slot, as the *modulus* of the hash against the table size is used.

Add your a custom `__eq__` method that returns `True` when two instances are supposed to be equal:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, type(self)):
        return False
    # all instances of this class are considered equal to one another
    return True
```

Comment: Curious why it needs both methods, is there some performance benefit where it checks hash first before eq?

Comment: @Davos sets are implemented as [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). And yes, using a hash table means set membership tests take O(1) constant time versus O(N) for lists, so it’s a performance choice.